# CEWP on Allitems.aspx in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: web-part, development, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint 2010 Discussion board and would like to add a Content Editor Webpart on Allitems.aspx page of it. I understood that we can not directly add a CEWP into the page however should use the SharePoint 2010 Designer for it. If I open the page on Sharepoint 2010 Designer, it does not allow me to add a new webpart/webpart zone. How can we add a new CEWP on the allitems.aspx page in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I have changed the default content type from 'Discussion' to 'Message' is on the Discussion Board on SharePoint 2010 and reverted. Now, If I click on the 'Add new Discussion',it is referring the Message content type and opening the window without Subject Field and the saved item is not getting displayed (yes, message content type will not be shown in Allitems.aspx page). How can I restore the orginial settings?

Comment: That is a separate question and should be raised separately.

Comment: though its a different question, it is related to the above one. It should be helpful for someone who is looking for the answer of both. If you still want, i can post this as a different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually customise AllItems.aspx through the browser, it's just not immediately obvious how to do it.

Go to **Site Actions** >> **Edit Page** and you will see a web part zone you can add a CEWP into it.

Comment: List Button is nolonger visible, if I edit the page through the browser and that's why want to edit the page through sharepoint designer 2010.

Comment: If you select a list item, the library button returns. You won't be able to edit this page in designer (you can't edit the webpart zones of publishing pages in designer unless you detatch it from the page layout). Alternatively you could create a custom page layout and add your webpart zone to that.

Answer (score 2):

Web parts do not have to be in web part zones, they can exist statically within a page.

```
<PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart runat="server"             
    ID=""
    Title="" 
    Height=""
    Width=""
    WebUrl="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/ %>" 
    ListGuid="" 
    ListName="" 
    ServerTemplate="100" 
    FilterValue1=""
    FilterField1=""
    Filter1ChainingOperator="" 
    Filter2ChainingOperator="" 
    GroupByFieldType="" 
    GroupByDirection="" 
    SortByFieldType="" 
    GroupBy="" 
    AllowClose="False"
    AllowConnect="False" 
    AllowEdit="False" 
    AllowHide="False" 
    AllowMinimize="False" 
    AllowZoneChange="False" 
    AllowRemove="False" 
    ChromeType="TitleOnly"
    CommonViewFields="URL, URL;Link_x0020_Label, Text"
    ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
    DataSourceID="" 
    Description="Description" 
    DetailLink="" 
    Dir="Default"
    ExportControlledProperties="True" 
    ExportMode="All" 
    FrameState="Normal" 
    FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
    HelpLink="" 
    HelpMode="Modeless" 
    ItemLimit="-1" 
    IsIncluded="True" 
    IsIncludedFilter=""
    IsVisible="True" 
    MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." 
    PageSize="-1"
    PartImageLarge="" 
    PartImageSmall="" 
    PartOrder="0" 
    ShowWithSampleData="False" 
    ShowUntargetedItems="False" 
    SortBy="" 
    SuppressWebPartChrome="False" 
    UseCopyUtil="True"
    UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" 
    ViewContentTypeId=""
    WebPart="true"
    ZoneID="ImportedPartZone" 
    __WebPartId="{80B6C3B8-43FE-4087-AA72-4A88BA16F909}" 
    __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup">
</PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart>
```

Comment: On the allitems.aspx, I am able to edit the code is in only between  "<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main">" and "</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>", where should i add the code like you mentioned?